# If $f $ is $C ^1 $ does it follow that $H(\textbf {x})= f(\textbf {x}) - E \cdot \textbf {x}$ is $C^1 $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let let $f $ be of class $C ^1 $ and  define  $E = D f(\textbf {a}) $.

Now define

$$
H(\textbf {x})= f(\textbf {x}) - E \cdot \textbf {x}  
$$

Does it follow that $H $ is of class $C ^1 $?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: every linear map is smooth. The gradient of $\mathbf{x} \mapsto E \cdot \mathbf{x}$ is just $E$, the constant map.